# Chrome xpath expression for selenium does not find element

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, xpath

In a webpage I have the following elements:

```
....
<select class="widget-listbox form-control" size="6" multiple="multiple">
    <option data-value="sIPSCs%20from%20juvenile%20(P21-30)%20C57BL%2F6J%20male%20mice%20hippocampus%20CA1%20pyramidal%20cell%20(A1)" value="sIPSCs from juvenile (P21-30) C57BL/6J male mice hippocampus CA1 pyramidal cell (A1)" class="">sIPSCs&nbsp;from&nbsp;juvenile&nbsp;(P21-30)&nbsp;C57BL/6J&nbsp;male&nbsp;mice&nbsp;hippocampus&nbsp;CA1&nbsp;pyramidal&nbsp;cell&nbsp;(A1)</option>
    <option data-value="sIPSCs%20from%20juvenile%20(P21-30)%20C57BL%2F6J%20male%20mice%20hippocampus%20CA1%20pyramidal%20cell%20(A2)" value="sIPSCs from juvenile (P21-30) C57BL/6J male mice hippocampus CA1 pyramidal cell (A2)" class="">sIPSCs&nbsp;from&nbsp;juvenile&nbsp;(P21-30)&nbsp;C57BL/6J&nbsp;male&nbsp;mice&nbsp;hippocampus&nbsp;CA1&nbsp;pyramidal&nbsp;cell&nbsp;(A2)</option>
</select>
....
```

and I am trying the following xpath expression to select the first options element (for a selenium test):

```
//option[contains(text(),"sIPSC")]
//option[text()="sIPSCs from juvenile (P21-30) C57BL/6J male mice hippocampus CA1 pyramidal cell (A1)"]
//option[@value="sIPSCs from juvenile (P21-30) C57BL/6J male mice hippocampus CA1 pyramidal cell (A1)"]
//select/option[contains(text(),"sIPSC")]
//select/option[text()="sIPSCs from juvenile (P21-30) C57BL/6J male mice hippocampus CA1 pyramidal cell (A1)"]
//select/option[@value="sIPSCs from juvenile (P21-30) C57BL/6J male mice hippocampus CA1 pyramidal cell (A1)"]
```

but none shows any results (in chrome, `XPath Helper` Version 2.02; chrome version 70.0.3538.110). The element I look for is not inside a frame. I also want to select the *whole* string "sIPSCs from juvenile (P21-30) C57BL/6J male mice hippocampus CA1 pyramidal cell (A1)" which might be a variable. Just any string. I do not know beforehand how this string looks like...

What am I doing wrong this time? Shouldn't any of the above expressions work?

Comment: At least first one should work. Did you switch to frame? Show your code

Answer (score 2):

To select the first option as the desired element are [React](https://reactjs.org/) element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following (**Pythonic**) solutions:

- *XPath 1*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='widget-listbox form-control']/option[contains(@data-value,'(A1)')]"))).click()
  ```
- *XPath 2*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='widget-listbox form-control']/option[contains(@value,'(A1)')]"))).click()
  ```
- *XPath 3*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='widget-listbox form-control']/option[contains(.,'(A1)')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: No sorry, I want to select the element with the following complete string: "sIPSCs from juvenile (P21-30) C57BL/6J male mice hippocampus CA1 pyramidal cell (A1)" not just parts of it. Maybe I do not know that string beforehand...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like both options contain "sIPSC"

Try an xpath that identifies what is *unique* about the element, like this: `//option[contains(text(),"sIPSC")][contains(text(),"A1")]`

If you will always want the **first** option:
`//select/option[contains(text(),"sIPSC")][1]`

Comment: No sorry, I want to select the element with the following complete string: "sIPSCs from juvenile (P21-30) C57BL/6J male mice hippocampus CA1 pyramidal cell (A1)" not just parts of it. Maybe I do not know that string beforehand...